# Como obtener valor al colocar atributo enable false c# aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas noches quisiera que me puedan ayudar tengo un combobox que por defecto tiene un valor 4   y en el codebing le colocado en el load combobox.enable=false ;

Pero cuando lo guarda ese valor que es 4 se coloca 0

Como si ese enable lo blanquea el valor 
Quisiera que me ayuden y no se pueda eliminar el valor cuando es ese combo es un enable

He intentado quitar el enable y si logra guardar el valor que por defecto le puesto.

Estoy realizando en aspx c#

Comment: La manera como describes tu problema puede ser por varios factores que este ocurriendo ese error. Podrías [edit] tu pregunta e incluir el código para poder resproducirlo.

Comment: en que evento asignas los datos del combo? es en el Load del form

Answer (score 1):

Cuando pierdes el valor del combo lo mas probable es que estes cargando los items del control en el Load del webform, pero no lo realices dentro de `IsPostBack`, tu codigo deberia ser

```
public void Form1_Load(...)
{
    if(!IsPostBack){
       //aqui asignas el datasource del combo
    }
}
```

sino colocas el codigo que asigna los datos en ese bloque cuando se produce el post por un evento perderas la seleccion